# Cannot delete this question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deletion

I cannot delete the following question:

[Uniqueness of finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865221/uniqueness-of-finite-field)

Most probably, I clicked the reopen button by mistake. It says `can't delete as others are investing time to answer it.`

How do I delete it?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot delete it as it has two answers.

You can only delete a question you asked if it has no answer or a unique answer that has not received any upvote at all, where "answer" means "answer post that is not deleted."

Tangentially, I assume that the message you reproduced says "answer" not "ask."